# Cryptic Typescript compiler error using React: 'ComponentClass<StyledComponentProps<{}>>' is not assignable to type 'typeof MyComponent'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to use the Material UI 1.0 (beta) @withStyles annotation on a React component. The docs give a Javascript example (https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/customization/css-in-js), but it gives a compile error in Typescript. It actually emits ok and the app runs fine, so am just trying to rid the IDE of the error!

Here is my code:

```
@withStyles(styles)
class MyComponent extends React.Component<any, any> {
    manager: any;
    ...
}
```

This gives error:

```
TS1238: Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.
 Type 'ComponentClass<StyledComponentProps<{}>>' is not assignable to type 'typeof MyComponent'.
 Type 'Component<StyledComponentProps<{}>, ComponentState>' is not assignable to type 'MyComponent'.
 Property 'manager' is missing in type 'Component<StyledComponentProps<{}>, ComponentState>'.
```

I don't really understand this error. I can use the alternative non-annotated version like this:

```
const MyStyledComponent = withStyles(styles)(MyComponent);
```

and this compiles/runs without issues. I'd prefer to use annotations though, and I'd like to understand the error.

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What this means is that the [declared type of the `@withStyles` decorator](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/src/styles/withStyles.d.ts#L23):

```
export default function withStyles<P = {}, ClassNames = {}>(
  style: StyleRules | StyleRulesCallback,
  options?: WithStylesOptions
): (
  component: React.ComponentType<P & { classes: ClassNames; theme?: Theme }>
) => React.ComponentClass<P & StyledComponentProps<ClassNames>>;
```

doesn't actually meet the contract that TypeScript needs for class decorators, which is something more like:

```
declare function classDecorator(...args: any[]): <C> (c: C) => C;
```

The contract is pretty strict: it requires that the function output be a *subtype* of the input.  This has led people to have [problems](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14082) before.

---

If everything is working fine at runtime and you just want to silence the type checker, there's always good old `any`:

```
@(withStyles as any)(styles) // no error now
class MyComponent extends React.Component<any, any> {
    manager: any;
    ...
}
```

---

Or, you could go ahead and try to re-declare the type of `withStyles()` to be more friendly to decorators:

```
import { StyledComponentProps } from 'material-ui';
import { Theme } from 'material-ui/styles/createMuiTheme';
import { StyleRules, StyleRulesCallback, WithStylesOptions } from 'material-ui/styles/withStyles';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles'
declare module 'material-ui/styles' {
  export function withStyles(
    style: StyleRules | StyleRulesCallback,
    options?: WithStylesOptions
  ): <C extends React.ComponentType<P & { classes: ClassNames; theme?: Theme }>, P = {}, ClassNames = {}> (
      component: C
    ) => C & React.ComponentClass<P & StyledComponentProps<ClassNames>>;

}
@withStyles(styles) // no error now
class MyComponent extends React.Component<any, any> {
  manager: any;
}
```

Now everything works because I ensure that the returned value is a subtype of the `MyComponent` constructor.  It's a lot of someone else's code to fix in your own project; I'd probably just use the `any` solution myself.

Whether someone wants to contact the [Material UI folks](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui) and suggest updating the definition is up to them.  I don't consider myself knowledgeable enough on React et al. to understand if my altered declaration is appropriate.

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: I think this is covered by this issue: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/8059

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to use @jcalz's type definition since it conflicts with the existing one, so I made a wrapper function.

Having `classes` be required on `WithStyles` also makes it a pain to use decorated components, so I make it optional instead.

```js
// withStyles.ts

import { Theme } from 'material-ui/styles';
import _withStyles, {
  ClassNameMap,
  StyledComponentProps,
  StyleRules,
  StyleRulesCallback,
  WithStylesOptions,
} from 'material-ui/styles/withStyles';

export interface WithStyles<ClassKey extends string = string> {
  classes?: ClassNameMap<ClassKey>;
  theme?: Theme;
}

// We need to fix the withStyles definition and we want to make WithStyles.classes optional,
// so we make our own.
export const withStyles = <ClassKey extends string>(
  style: StyleRules<ClassKey> | StyleRulesCallback<ClassKey>,
  options?: WithStylesOptions
) => <C extends React.ComponentType<P & WithStyles<ClassKey>>, P = {}>(component: C) => {
  return (_withStyles as any)(style, options)(component) as C & React.ComponentType<P & StyledComponentProps<ClassKey>>;
};
```

To use it just import the new `withStyles.ts` instead of the `material-ui` one.

```js
import { withStyles, WithStyles } from './withStyles';

@withStyles(styles)
export class MyClass extends React.Component<MyClassProps> {
  render() {
    // classes will always exist so use `!`.
    const classes = this.props.classes!;

    return (
      <div className={classes.root} />
    );
  }
}
```